Creating a glimmer effect animation with a curve. How to control the glimmer with a BW mask?
Im trying to create this glimmer as you can see here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woman_Worldwide#/media/File:Woman_Worldwide.jpg
By turning it into a curve with an emission material and a black and white mask so I can animate the light to make it shimmer.
I want the white part of the BW to be placed across the text so that the entire section becomes light, is it possible?
The setup:

File:


Also, if there is a better solution let me know!
